# Zip local files prior to an update with Inno Setup

Tags: zip, inno-setup

When running new releases of my installer I would like to make a backup of an existing installation by adding files into a ZIP archive.

Currently, I am able to make a backup of an existing installation by coping the files to my `Backup` destination.  A simplified version of the method I use is as follows:

```
[Files]
; Copy the contents of Bin folder to Backup folder. Skip if files don’t exist. 
Source: {app}\Bin\*;  DestDir: {app}\Backup\; \
    Flags: createallsubdirs external recursesubdirs uninsneveruninstall skipifsourcedoesntexist;
```

I would appreciate any ideas how I can zip instead?

Comment: I think e.g. 7-zip, or zlib DLLs could be used to pack the files (if it's possible to translate their function exports into Inno Setup). Or, you can write a very simple single purpose DLL by yourself (as I've seen you're a native language programmer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used TLama's suggestion and created my own DLL in Delphi (XE3) that zips a folder.

```pascal
library MyZipLib;
uses
  Winapi.Windows,
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Zip;

{$R *.res}

function ZipCompressFolder(SourcePath, DestinationPath, ArchiveName : PChar): boolean; stdcall;
begin
  //If source folder does not exist then exit without error.
  if not DirectoryExists(SourcePath) then
  begin
    result := true;
    exit;
  end;

  try
    result := false;

    //Make sure destination path exists
    ForceDirectories(DestinationPath);
    TZipFile.ZipDirectoryContents(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(DestinationPath) + ArchiveName, SourcePath);
    result := true;
  except
    on E : Exception do MessageBox(0, PChar('Error calling function ZipCompressFolder@MyZipLib.dll with message: ' + E.Message + #13#10 + 'Source: ' + SourcePath + #13#10 + 'Dest: ' + DestinationPath+ #13#10 + 'Archive: ' + ArchiveName), 'MyZipLib.dll Error', MB_OK);
  end;
end;

exports ZipCompressFolder;
begin
end.
```

Answer (score 2):

you may want to check out LOGAN ISSI : http://members.home.nl/albartus/inno/index.html  there are some utils bundled with it.

Another method would be to include a batch file which will carry out the backup steps and then get it to remove itself once complete.

checkout this thread: [Batch script to zip all the files without the parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696606/batch-script-to-zip-all-the-files-without-the-parent-folder)

however due to licensing you are not allowed to bundle rar.dll with your app so just apply this method but use a package/dll which can be redistributed.

If you can use VBScript to code a simple wrapper you can also make use of windows built in zip compression.

See how you: [Can Windows' built-in ZIP compression be scripted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30211/can-windows-built-in-zip-compression-be-scripted)

Answer (score 1):

If you know that you are installing on a machine that has .NET 4.5 and newer (i.e. on Windows 8 and newer), you can use PowerShell and .NET 4.5 [`ZipFile` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile) from [`CurStepChanged(ssInstall)` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged).

```pascal
[Code]

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  Command, AppPath, ZipName, ZipTmpPath, ZipPath: string;
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  if CurStep = ssInstall then
  begin
    AppPath := ExpandConstant('{app}');
    if not DirExists(AppPath) then
    begin
      Log(Format('Application path "%s" does not exist, ' +
        ' probably fresh install, not backing up', [AppPath]));
    end
      else
    begin
      ZipName := 'backup.zip';
      ZipTmpPath := ExpandConstant('{tmp}') + '\' + ZipName;  
      ZipPath := AppPath + '\' + ZipName;  
      if FileExists(ZipPath) then
      begin
        if DeleteFile(ZipPath) then
          Log(Format('Archive ZIP "%s" exists, deleted', [ZipPath]))
        else
          RaiseException(Format(
            'Archive ZIP "%s" exists, and it could not be deleted', [ZipPath]));
      end;

      Log(Format('Archiving application folder "%s" to temporary "%s"', [
        AppPath, ZipTmpPath]));
      Command :=
        'Add-Type -Assembly System.IO.Compression.FileSystem ; ' +
        '[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory(''' +
          AppPath + ''', ''' + ZipTmpPath +''')';
      if Exec('powershell', '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command "' + Command + '"',
           '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) and
         (ResultCode = 0) then
      begin
        Log(Format('Application folder "%s" archived to temporary "%s"', [
          AppPath, ZipTmpPath]));
      end
        else
      begin
        RaiseException(Format('Error archiving application folder "%s" "%s"', [
          AppPath, ZipTmpPath]));
      end;

      if FileCopy(ZipTmpPath, ZipPath, False) then
        Log(Format('Copied "%s" to "%s"', [ZipTmpPath, ZipPath]))
      else
        RaiseException(Format('Error copying "%s" to "%s"', [
          ZipTmpPath, ZipPath]));
    end;
  end;
end;
```

---

If you need to support even older versions of Windows, you might do with `Shell.Application` class. Though I was not able to make it create a ZIP file, only add to one. A solution might be to add an empty ZIP file to the installer,  and add to it.