# Inno Setup Copy Files and Folders to an Existing Zip File

Tags: vbscript, inno-setup

Is there a way to copy files from a folder to a zip file using Inno Setup?

My installer script creates a Temp Folder and I would like to move the content (mix of files and folders) to an existing zip file.  I don't need compression or anything fancy...

I thought, and I know this is dumb, that this would be possible using FileCopy because (as far as I know) MS Windows treats copying to a zip folder in a similar way as copying to a directory.

[Update 1] Ok - [found a vbs script that does what I want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30211/can-windows-built-in-zip-compression-be-scripted/124775#124775), after some minor changes:

```
Dim fso, winShell, h, MyTarget, MySource

MySource = Wscript.Arguments.Item(0)
MyTarget = Wscript.Arguments.Item(1)

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set winShell = createObject("shell.application")
Set h = fso.getFile(MyTarget)

'Wscript.Echo "Adding " & MySource & " to " & MyTarget

winShell.NameSpace(MyTarget).CopyHere winShell.NameSpace(MySource).Items

do
    wscript.sleep 500
    max = h.size
loop while h.size > max 

Set winShell = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
```

And ran it from command line like this:
Cmd (run as admin)
C:\MyScriptLocation\WScript ZipScript.vbs "MySourceDirPath" "MyDestDirPath\MyZipFile.zip"

So now I need to get it to run from Inno :-)

[Update 2] Ok - got it running from Inno, revised the script:

```
Dim objFSO, objTxt, winShell, h
Dim myFolder, myZipFile
Const ForWriting = 2

myFolder = Wscript.Arguments.Item(0)
myZipFile = Wscript.Arguments.Item(1)
Wscript.Echo "Planning to add Source: " & myFolder & " to Target: " & myZipFile

Set objFSO = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )
Wscript.Echo "Creating myZipFile" & myZipFile
' Create an empty ZIP file
    Set objTxt = objFSO.OpenTextFile( myZipFile, ForWriting, True )
    objTxt.Write "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String( 18, Chr(0) )
    objTxt.Close
    Set objTxt = Nothing

Set winShell = createObject("shell.application")
Set h = objFSO.getFile(myZipFile)
Wscript.Echo "Started Copy Process" & myZipFile
winShell.NameSpace(myZipFile).CopyHere winShell.NameSpace(myFolder).Items, true

do
    wscript.sleep 1000
    max = h.size
loop while h.size > max 

Set winShell = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

I am running from Inno using:

```
[Run]
Filename: "PackItUp.vbs"; Parameters: """{code:GetDataDir_S|0}\Temp"" ""{code:GetDataDir_S|0}\myZip.zip"""; WorkingDir: "{code:GetDataDir_S|0}"; Flags: shellexec runascurrentuser
```

Which seems to work, but I am unsure if this is a good solution.

Comment: Not sure if this is a duplicate or not. TLama talks about there being no native support for archiving but some suggetions are offered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19832128/inno-setup-zip-local-files-prior-to-an-update). As per Tlama: _there is no built-in support of any archiver in Inno Setup_

Comment: Hi Matt - I don't think it is a duplicate. I have been searching for days, seriously. This is my first Inno experience and it is a steep learning curve for me from VBA.  I did see the article saying no native support, and the other article too - but I'm not after compression.

Comment: Wow, didn't know about this possibility. Very nice indeed!

Comment: Hey TLama - wow, I never expected to get a comment like that :-D thanks.

I have been reading loads of solutions from both you and Deanna and would like to take this opportunity to thank you both for sharing so much - Cheers,

Comment: Thanks :-) Btw., throw that VB script away. All this can be done on 3 lines of code (directly in Inno Setup Pascal Script using late binding). I'll be right back... (well, maybe more if we consider using flags for the [`CopyHere`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787866(v=vs.85).aspx) method).

Comment: Cool - I'd love to know how... :-D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a nice feature that I've never heard about. The [`Folder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787868(v=vs.85).aspx) object [`CopyHere`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787866(v=vs.85).aspx) method can append files or folders to existing archive files. With late binding you can write as little as this (even the VB script in your question was overcomplicated since this method accepts also file name passed as string):

```
procedure CopyToArchive(const Archive, Content: string);
var
  Shell: Variant;
  Folder: Variant;
begin
  Shell := CreateOleObject('Shell.Application');
  Folder := Shell.NameSpace(Archive);
  Folder.CopyHere(Content);
end;
```

The `Archive` parameter in the above function must be the name of an existing archive file (I've tested only ZIP archive since I don't know what other formats Windows Shell supports this way). The `Content` parameter can be the name of the file or folder that you want to include to the given archive file. Usage can be like this. The first call shows how to copy file to the archive, the second how to copy folder:

```
CopyToArchive('C:\ExistingArchive.zip', 'C:\FileToCopy.txt');
CopyToArchive('C:\ExistingArchive.zip', 'C:\FolderToCopy\');
```

The [`CopyHere`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787866(v=vs.85).aspx) method also provides a set of options, by which you can refine behavior of this method. Since I'm not sure which options can be used for archives and since there's a lot of combinations, I'll just post here their translation and the way how to use them keeping their (optional) usage on you (for more information see the linked MSDN reference):

```
[Code]
const
  FOF_SILENT = $0004; // do not display a progress dialog box
  FOF_RENAMEONCOLLISION = $0008; // give the file being operated on a new name in a move, copy, or rename operation if a file with the target name already exists
  FOF_NOCONFIRMATION = $0010; // respond with "Yes to All" for any dialog box that is displayed
  FOF_ALLOWUNDO = $0040; // preserve undo information, if possible
  FOF_FILESONLY = $0080; // perform the operation on files only if a wildcard file name (*.*) is specified
  FOF_SIMPLEPROGRESS = $0100; // display a progress dialog box but do not show the file names
  FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR = $0200; // do not confirm the creation of a new directory if the operation requires one to be created
  FOF_NOERRORUI = $0400; // do not display a user interface if an error occurs
  FOF_NOCOPYSECURITYATTRIBS = $0800; // do not copy the security attributes of the file
  FOF_NORECURSION = $1000; // only operate in the local directory. Do not operate recursively into subdirectories
  FOF_NO_CONNECTED_ELEMENTS = $2000; // do not copy connected files as a group. Only copy the specified files

procedure CopyToArchive(const Archive, Content: string);
var
  Shell: Variant;
  Folder: Variant;
begin
  Shell := CreateOleObject('Shell.Application');
  Folder := Shell.NameSpace(Archive);
  // this will display the progress dialog and suppress showing errors
  Folder.CopyHere(Content, FOF_SIMPLEPROGRESS or FOF_NOERRORUI);
end;
```

Comment: TLama - thank you.  I spent days looking for a solution to this, the VBS works well in the few hours that I have spent testing it. Really keen to test out your refined approach. Glad we can learn something together :-)