# Create ZIP files from within Inno Setup

Tags: zip, compression, inno-setup, archive

I want to ZIP some log files generated by inner setups (dependencies) so they become a single file that is easy to send back for support purposes.

Is there an easy way to do this using Inno Setup?

If everything else fails, I can always use some minimal ZIP.EXE utility to achieve this but I am not sure which would be legal to embed and use. I am hoping to find a built-in solution if possible but I'd settle for an external app.

Actually, I am not looking for ZIP format in particular. Any archive that wraps multiple files together (and possibly compresses them) is ideal.

Comment: I use ZIP format. Created a zip dll in Delphi. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19832128/inno-setup-zip-local-files-prior-to-an-update?lq=1 for details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in archiving support in Inno Setup.

See [Inno Setup – zip local files prior to an update](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19832128/850848)

---

If you do not look for a particular archive format, use Microsoft's `.cab` format. There's a command-line tool to create these in all modern versions of Windows (XP and up at least), the [`makecab`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/makecab).

So you do not need to distribute your own archiving binary.

Comment: This sounds perfect! I thought of CAB myself but I wasn't sure if there was a consistent way to use it across Windows versions. Thanks!